# How to structure django + react project for deployment?

Tags: reactjs, django, deployment

I'm building a django + django-rest-framework project with react as frontend. I've look around for the best way to structure and deploy it and it seems there are several aproaches. One is to build the react frontend as static files and have django serve them, another one is to have 2 diffeernt servers and let both projects comunicate over http. Which is the better option? What are the pros and cons of each aproach? It seems the latter one would be more expensive since we have to pay for both servers.
Notes:

- The project is realatively small but can end up evolving into a larger one.
- We are using a MySQL database
- We want the option to use the django admin webpage